# How to get rid of Docstring warning (blue squiggly lines) from python in Visual studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently learning how to code in python, and my preferred IDE is visual studio code. It keeps giving me DOCSTRING warnings which show up as a blue squiggly lines under every function an variables. I found a short term solution which is to paste this at the top of the file:

```py
# pylint: disable=missing-module-docstring
# pylint: disable=missing-class-docstring
# pylint: disable=missing-function-docstring
# pylint: disable=invalid-name
# pylint: disable=trailing-newlines
# pylint: disable=trailing-whitespace
# pylint: disable=missing-final-newline
```

its annoying that I have to do this in order to not see the blue squiggly lines and also it looks unprofessional. i have tried very hard for two days before coming here to ask for help, I even asked Chatgpt for help and did exactly what it told me to do. I don't know if I'm doing this right or not. I am trying to copy and paste this :

`"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=C0111"]`

in setting.json.

Comment: RIOV8 thank you for editing my question looks much more neater now. I am new to this and I want learn how to formulate questions properly, how do format my code to look neat ?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is a guide to the markdown syntax. Welcome to SO!